# Pass multiple pass values to RedirectToAction in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing the website in MVC. I want to display details record one by one. The next record to be displayed when user clicks the Submit Button. 
Kindly advise for the same 
Code in Controller

```
  // GET: Member_Details
   public ActionResult Member_Details(int sysmemberid , string type)
        {
            Member_Details obj = new Member_Details();
            obj=obj.getMemberDetails(Convert.ToInt64(Session["Id"]), sysmemberid, type);// assign values to model
            Session["sysmemberid"] = sysmemberid;
            Session["type"] = type;
            Session["Next"] = obj.next;
            return View(obj);
        }



 [HttpPost]
     public void Member_Details(Member_Details obj ,string command)
     {
         string sysmemberid = Session["sysmemberid"].ToString();
         string type1 = Session["type"].ToString();
         string sqlQuery = "";
         int next = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Next"]);   
         RedirectToAction("Member_Details", new { sysmemberid = next, type = type1 });
}
```

View Code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Member_Details", "Member_Details", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
{
   // Code to bind model
   <button type="submit" id="btnSave" name="command" value="invite" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block link dtlSubmit">Connect</button>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like you already have the logic to get the next item and are building the `ReditectToAction`, however it doesn't look like you are returning it.

Add the `ActionResult` return value to the `Member_Details` that handles the POST:

```
public ActionResult Member_Details(Member_Details obj ,string command)
```

And return your `RedirectToAction`:

```
     return RedirectToAction("Member_Details", new { sysmemberid = next, type = type1 });
```